# Hello Everyone , API data storage issue in release built and not in debug built , any step that i am doing wrong?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-volley

> I am storing a response on login in shared preference , its working
>   fine in debug mode where the data is coming like user id but in
>   release built all the data are coming null , i am using volley and
>   share preference.And Idea about the issue?

```
private void hitLoginIn() {

        String url = Global.BASE_URL + Global.LOGIN_API;
        cancel_login_api=url;
        StringRequest jsonObjReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {                       
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            if (API.success(obj))
                            {
                                Utils.storeUserPreferences(LoginActivity.this, Global.USER, API.getData(obj));

                                Intent skip = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                startActivity(skip);
                            } else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, ""+API.rMessage(obj), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }                           
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("user_login", edt_email.getText().toString().trim());
                params.put("user_login_password", edt_password.getText().toString().trim());
                return params;
            }
        };

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, cancel_login_api);
    }
```

My App Gradle which consists of all the the code of the gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.snapit.up"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                shrinkResources false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.hkk595:Resizer:v1.3'
    compile 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
}
```

Comment: can you please check minifyEnabled is true or false in app build.gradle?

Comment: Have you enabled proguard in release mode..

if miminifyEnabled true, 
do you have written proguard configuration for volley library.

Please provide your build.gradle file and proguard-rules.pro or proguard-android.txt file

Comment: buildTypes {
        release {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Please check i have updated my gradle code in my issue

Comment: Thank you ,@MilanHirpara , @ Mitesh Machhoya your doubt made my app work thanks